# Brown lawn with weeds, how to remedy?

Tags: landscaping, lawn

We have a house and the lawn is in this state. 
There are brown patches, there are barren areas, there are weeds.

What are the steps to remedy this and  'bring' the grass back?

FYI:
We live in Los Angeles.

That's a Magnolia tree in our yard.

We've been just manually weeding. We've also started watering every other day for about a week.

[image: brown lawn]

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?  Also what kind of tree is that?

Comment: Just added the details that you guys are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for migrating.  I didn't realize this forum existed!

Comment: Looks like drought and cutting the grass too short - were you not watering before this happened? Has the weather been hot and dry for a while? What type of grass is it?

Comment: Didn't water it for months and we get temps sometimes in the 80s. We don't get a lot of rain. I started watering it last week. I don't know the type of grass. I'll post close up pictures later. We do get weeds that grow.

Comment: It looks to me like it just needs frequent and deep watering BUT, where you live, that's a problem by the looks of it, I found this on line http://lacity.dev2-cityofla.acsitefactory.com/311-directory-online-services/servicedetail/3909. What does everyone else's lawn look like, are they the same as yours?

Comment: Other people water their lawns and have gardeners so the lawns are green. So if I deep water now will the grass come back to life?

Comment: I don't know much about other grasses that might be used over there for lawns, but grass (fescue, bents, rye) in the UK will green up once rain arrives or if its well watered, and not cut too short till its recovered. I can certainly see some hints of green in yours, but from the link I posted, you may well be breaking the law watering so much, not sure